# Is it safe to install Ubuntu on a mid 2014 retina Macbook Pro?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, mac, macbook

I am currently interested in installing ubuntu on my Macbook Pro. I wish to know if it is safe to install Ubuntu as a full replacement of Mac OS X or if I should install with dual-boot first. This concern is mostly because of an apparent incompatibility between Ubuntu and Apple's custom EFI implementation, which by my understanding can "brick" my laptop.

I also looked for guides on how to replace Mac OS X with Ubuntu but the ones I found are old, and the software that they use (namely reEFIt) does not seem to work well on OS X Yosemite. Can someone point me to more recent tutorials/guides?

Lastly, is Ubuntu 15.04 capable of scaling everything (excluding applications) well?

[Edit]: I followed the instructions on Ubuntu's website and created an bootable USB, and when 15.04 loaded, I could not get a Wi-Fi connection. Being the first available release of 15.04, should I wait a couple more days and try again or should I assume that Wi-Fi is not available out-of-the-box with VividVerdet?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to dual boot because there are still some driver issues. Namely around the discrete GPU and the webcam. I wrote a blog post about doing just this which you might find helpful [1], the last step explains how to get WIFI working.

[1] http://fromanegg.com/post/82251710943/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-or-macbook

Comment: Your link appears to be dead. I can't see your post.
I own a 13" version the retina macbook pro, which does not offer dual-graphic cards. Having only the Intel Iris integrated graphics, would you advise installing 15.04?

Comment: Sorry about that, the site is back up. I haven't yet done the upgrade but others haven't reported any issues.